# Cloudera CDH4 Eclipse connection refused error

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I'm trying to configure eclipse 'hadoop location' MR and DFS hosts and ports, but I get 'connection refused' errors. I have virtual machine manager and node1 in a cloudera setup (from here http://www.spaggiari.org/index.php/hbase/hbase-and-hadoop-with-cloudera#.UiuUjOEyY0g and I use host only networking).

nmap results:

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
111/tcp open  rpcbind
```

node1:

```
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
8002/tcp  open  teradataordbms
8021/tcp  open  ftp-proxy
8888/tcp  open  sun-answerbook
9000/tcp  open  cslistener
9010/tcp  open  sdr
60020/tcp open  unknown
```

I can ping and ssh to them, and cloudera tells me hdfs and map-reduce etc are all running fine.

I have tried all sorts of combinations for the hosts and ports

(using http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Free/4.5.4/Configuring-Ports-for-Cloudera-Manager-Free-Edition/cmfecp_topic_3.html)

but keep getting connection refused.

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Run host inspector and try resolving all the errors. Pls post the logs of the connection refused error. I had faced this issue before, and it got resolved when all host inspector errors where cleared(basically conflicts in host file which are multiple alias for same ip, for this make sure hostname comes first)